# stringr: Removing Parentheses and Brackets from string

Tags: r, string, stringr

I want to remove parentheses and brackets from a string. I got the required result, however looking for more compact method.

```
Test <- c("-0.158)", "0.426)", "1.01)", "1.6)", "2.18)", "2.77]")

stringr::str_replace(
  string = Test
  , pattern = "\\)"
  , replacement = ""
)

# [1] "-0.158" "0.426"  "1.01"   "1.6"    "2.18"   "2.77]" 
stringr::str_replace(
    string = Test
  , pattern = "\\]"
  , replacement = ""
)

# [1] "-0.158)" "0.426)"  "1.01)"   "1.6)"    "2.18)"   "2.77"  
stringr::str_replace(
  string = stringr::str_replace(
            string = Test
            , pattern = "\\]"
            , replacement = ""
          )
  , pattern = "\\)"
  , replacement = ""
)

# [1] "-0.158" "0.426"  "1.01"   "1.6"    "2.18"   "2.77"
```

Wonder if it can be obtained with a single command something like this

```
stringr::str_replace(
  string = Test
  , pattern = "\\)^]"
  , replacement = ""
)
```

**Edited**

Found a very simple solution

```
readr::parse_number(Test) 
[1] -0.158 0.426 1.010 1.600 2.180 2.770.
```

Comment: Found a very simple solution `readr::parse_number(Test)
[1] -0.158  0.426  1.010  1.600  2.180  2.770`.

Comment: I also thought about `parse_number`.  But, if there are multiple patterns within a string, it extracts the first instance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We can use `|`

```
gsub("\\)|\\]", "", Test)
#[1] "-0.158" "0.426"  "1.01"   "1.6"    "2.18"   "2.77"
```

or instead of escaping place the brackets inside the `[]`

```
gsub("[][()]", "", Test)
#[1] "-0.158" "0.426"  "1.01"   "1.6"    "2.18"   "2.77"
```

---

If we want to do the extract instead of removing use either `gregexpr/regmatches` from `base R` or `str_extract` from `stringr` to check for patterns where a number could start with `-` and include `.`

```
library(stringr)
str_extract(Test, "-?[0-9.]+")
#[1] "-0.158" "0.426"  "1.01"   "1.6"    "2.18"   "2.77"
```

Comment: Thanks @akrun for useful answer. Wonder if there is function to extract numbers only from a string.

Comment: @MYaseen208  Updated with an option.  Hope it helps